# Graphs with small number of edges and large eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $G_n$ be a sequence of simple graphs on $n$ vertices. I am trying to construct graphs such that the number of edges in $G_n$ is at most $(1-\varepsilon)\frac{n^2}{4}$, and the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of $G_n$ is at least $(1+\delta)\frac{n}{2}$, for some $\varepsilon, \delta>0$, and all large $n$.

I am trying to do this by adding a few ($o(n)$ many) large degree vertices to a random graph with edge probability $(1-\varepsilon)/2$ but that is not working. I will appreciate any hints or references. Thanks in advance.